# Why the result of "dir" doesn't have highlighting?

Tags: linux, bash, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I'm on Oracle Linux.

```
[root@ol76 systemd]# cat /etc/*release*
Oracle Linux Server release 7.6
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6"
ID="ol"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.6"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:6:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
Oracle Linux Server release 7.6
cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:6:server
[root@ol76 systemd]#
```

Why the result of `ls` has highlighting, but `dir` doesn't?

[image]

Comment: `dir --color=auto`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you. Could you make it as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: I just found `ls` also has `color` parameter. `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Comment: Done it. Sorry for the spanish, I can't change my LC_ALL to english, but I provide some translation :)

Comment: @guillermochamorro `LC_ALL=C dir --help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `dir --help`:

> Using color to distinguish file types is disabled both by default and
>   with `--color=never`.  With `--color=auto`, `ls` emits color codes only when
>   standard output is connected to a terminal.  The `LS_COLORS` environment
>   variable can change the settings.  Use the `dircolors` command to set
>   it.